# One-Way Data Flow: Child component doesn't update when prop is asynchronously updated by parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and
> the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to
> the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child
> components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can
> make your app’s data flow harder to reason about. In addition, every
> time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component
> will be refreshed with the latest value. - [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

The [Vue2 Component Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) suggests doing the following to use props as an initial value:

```
// via https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
  return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

So in my code I mimicked those instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/komplexb/9bc09823ebc831aa2dc5269641c048dc/2e2815ef021fff3f601dbfb3eacc802a7f2980eb).
However data() in Note.vue isn't being updated even though the prop value is received according to vue-devtools.
[image]

Haven't had success setting the values with the `mounted` or `created` lifescyle methods.

When I use static data, this seems to work fine, how can I ensure the child component reacts to receiving props when it comes from a remote source?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing `initialNote` as prop for initial value, but I see `initialNote` is being populated asynchronously in `getNote` method, so it will not be present initially when the component will be mounted. It will be populated after some time by the time initialisation would have already happened.

In the example give in [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), `initialCounter` is static value which will perfect as it will have same value from beginning.

Comment: Right I've observed that. However doesn't Vue continuously observe/watch the data object/function for changes and propagate those changes to the children using data items as props? 

Also when I check vue-devtools the props are received, but the fields in Note.vue aren't updated as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYFbh.png)

Comment: @komplexb Yes, vue watches for data change and changed props are propagated to child, but initialisation happens only once when child component is mounted, initial value does not change. If you want changes you can use prop `initialNote` itself in `Note` instead of local data variables.